# Programmatically change height of navigation bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to make a taller navigation bar and I am trying to do this using a subclass of UINavigationBar.

Here is my subclass of UINavigationBar:

```
import UIKit
class TallerNaviBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, 87)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

And in my ViewController which is embedded in a navigation controller, I write the following code in the viewDidLoad() function

```
self.navigationController!.setValue(TallerNaviBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 87)), forKeyPath: "navigationBar")
```

There is no error reported, but I get nothing when I run the code. A completely blank view. [image].

Any suggestion? Or some other way of changing the height? Thanks.

Comment: there's the answer in swift, nice down vote, you are welcome

Comment: @Larcerax. Thank you for your answer. But my reputation point is only 8, which means I am not allowed to down vote. Sorry for the down vote you got, but it is not me.

Comment: so, the first answer there is the right answer, the one with the : self.superview!.frame.size.width, 87) try it out, and you will see it should work just fine, type cast the viewcontroller, if you know how to do this in Swift, sorry about the prejudgment

Comment: @Larcerax. And I cannot upvote either or I will recover your loss. The minimum for upvote is 15 and the minimum for down vote is 125. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: you are good to go, don't worry, i have the other type casting for you that may work,

Comment: read my answer again, the top part

Comment: @Larcerax it works! Thanks!

Comment: Oh perfect! i tried to figure out the type cast for Swift, but I'm just a Obj C guy, I'm glad you got it to work, it took me forever to figure this one out when I was in your shoes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**update for iOS 11 and beyond**

apple doesn't want you messing with the navigation bar height, so don't touch it
see here: https://openradar.appspot.com/32912789
and here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88202#274620

```
class TallerNaviBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(self.superview!.frame.size.width, 87)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

I don't do swift, but the answer is easy, here's ObjC

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

         return CGSizeMake([self superview].frame.size.width, 40);

}
```

Here's my interpretation in Swift:

```
import UIKit
class TallerNaviBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(superview.width, 87)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

The problem you will have isn't with this method, this is the easy part, the problem is forcing the navigation controller to always use this navigation bar

I subclass and resize everything in IOS, including navigation controllers and tabbarcontrollers, in order to enforce that all navigation controllers use this navigation bar, you must subclass a navigationController and only use this navigationcontroller throughout your app, here's how the subclass works, this is Obj C, so you'll have to translate it:

```
@interface NSHNavigationController () <UINavigationBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{

}

@implementation NSHNavigationController

#pragma mark Initialization

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self NSHSetupNavigationController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass
{
    self = [super initWithNavigationBarClass:navigationBarClass toolbarClass:toolbarClass];
    if (self) {
        [self NSHSetupNavigationController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if (self) {
        [self NSHSetupNavigationController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self NSHSetupNavigationController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self setInternalDelegate:nil];
    [self setExternalDelegate:nil];
}

#pragma mark Setup

- (void)NSHSetupNavigationController
{
    [self setValue:[[NSHNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
}
```

this is the line that will do it for you:

```
   [self setValue:[[NSHNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

Oh yeah, and make sure you are subclassing the nav bar, you said you were, but here's how you do it, it's simple:

```
#import "NSHNavigationBar.h"

@implementation NSHNavigationBar
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                     NSFontAttributeName:fontMagicForRegularNSHFont};
        [self setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
        [self setTranslucent:true];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    return CGSizeMake([self superview].frame.size.width, heightResizer(40));

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

}
```

So, in summary, subclass both the UINavigationBar and the UINavigationController and you are set, this will allow you to manipulate the navigation bar whenever you'd like, you can also type cast your view controller's navigation bars, this is a little nuts and will confuse a lot of people, but here it goes:

```
-(CustomNavigationBar *)navBar {

    return (id)[self.navigationController navigationBar];
}
```

put the stuff above in your view controller and then you call it like this:

```
[[self navBar] setBackGroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

This will successfully typecast your navigationcontroller to be your custom navigation bar, if you want to change the height of the nav bar from here, then you can do something like this:

Comment: Not working on iOS 11. I created subclass of UINavigationController and UINavigationBar as described above. In storyboard, changed the class names of UINavigationController and UINavigationBar to the respective subclass names. But height is not changing.

Comment: @Vakas it's no longer supported see here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88202#274620 and here: https://openradar.appspot.com/32912789 apple doesn't want you messing with the navigation bar height, so i'd leave it alone, tell your client to F off

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple Swift 3 solution based on minimal subclassing. First subclass UINavigationBar.:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let newSize :CGSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 54)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

Create the navigation controller in code and use the initializer that takes your custom navigation bar class.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: CustomNavigationBar.self, 
                                 toolbarClass: nil)
```

All existing behavior for UINavigationBar is preserved and your custom height is adopted.

Comment: How to set custom navigation bar class inside UIStoryboard? I tried changing the class name but it doesn't work.

Comment: sizeThatFits is not support anymore in ios11

Comment: how to set rootViewController?