# iOS - Resizing Navigation Bar height with detail

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to make a navigation bar that changes height in it's detail view just like the messages app in iOS 10. How can I do that?

**Edit:**

I am looking to change the height dynamically. SizeThatFits() Permanently changes the height.

[image: Resizing Navigation Bar]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change height of navigation bar in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006330/programmatically-change-height-of-navigation-bar-in-swift)

Comment: The article you sent me asks to set a custom height. I want mine to resize when it's in detail.

Comment: Apple has a sample app that shows a few different modifications to the navigation bar, including something quite similar - probably a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I have checked the sample app but the extended navigation bar doesn't have the same behaviour as the gif in my question. The sample app has a UIView added below and the gif's Navigation Bar resizes when it goes into detail.

Comment: @evenwerk did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do something else that requires the navigation bar to be resized, that's not supported. `iOS 11` and Above
[Community bug reports](https://openradar.appspot.com/32912789)